# Ubuntu clean Dev loop2 and loop51 error when booting

Tags: boot

Anyone familiar with this error I get when booting?

Ubuntu: clean, 1676982/12615680 files, 34413733/50453248 blocks

Dev loop2: unable to read RDB block 8

Dev loop51: unable to read RDB block 8

[image]